finalize() method not throwing unhandled exceptions
The finalize() method seems to be catching unhandled exceptions and not doing anything with them.
Running the following code in my angular project, the console log will run but nothing after the thrown error (expected).
But, there is no evidence of the thrown error, in devtools or anywhere else.
Is there any reason for this? I can't see anywhere defining this as intended functionality. And being the last action of a subscription I do not think passing this error to catchError() makes sense.
this.obsService.getSubject().pipe(finalize(() => {
  console.log(1);
  throw new Error('Finalize issue');
  this.performFinalActions();
})).subscribe();

Should this just be logged as an issue with RxJS directly?
EDIT: An error is thrown currectly if getSubject is a RxJS Subject but if another observable such as HttpClient.get the error dissappears from any logs.


Throw new error stops execution of code after it happens, so the below code is dead code (performFinalActions).

We need to emit values from the subject for the error to be shown on console.

The finalize happens after the error happens so it's working fine.

The finalize code will happen only after the subject is completed, else it won't be called.


Working example below:
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { finalize, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

function performFinalActions() {
  console.log('performing actions');
}
const subject$ = new Subject();

subject$
  .pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      console.log(1);
      throw new Error('Finalize issue');
      performFinalActions();
    })
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: (data: any) => console.log('next', data),
    error: (data: any) => console.log('error', data),
    complete: () => {
      console.log('complete');
    },
  });

subject$.next('asdf');
subject$.complete();

Stackblitz Demo

Strange, in your demo, this works as I'd expect. An error is thrown at unsubscription. However, if I copy this code into my angular project no error is thrown. And yes the dead code doesn't run.

@StarskyTorchia check if your debugger tools  (console window) is filtering out error messages!

Okay so it gets more complex. Your demo works for me, the error is thrown correctly (in my angular project). But if subject$ is a HttpClient request observable it dissappears. So this issue may be specific to the HttpClient class.
